# What accent is Kanbaru referring to, and where did she live prior to her parents' deaths?

Tags: monogatari-series

In chapter 34 of the *Bakemonogatari* manga, Kanbaru talks about her past. When she discusses her living situation after the death of her parents, she says:

> I was bullied at the school I transferred to, simply put. I still have an accent now, but it was a lot worse back then. I had a lot of problems myself, but my head was filled with my parents.

What accent is she referring to? While I can find a mention of Kagenui having a Kansai accent, I can't find anything for Kanbaru at all, both explicitly in regards to her accent and in regards to where she was living before her parents died, which might provide some information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not recall any mention in the anime, either. A quick look at the light novels, however, seem to reveal some information, albeit also vague. To quote from **Chapter 7** of *Bakemonogatari: Monster Tale Part 02*:

> The way I spoke was different. I might talk like this now, but when I was still with my parents, **we were all the way out on the tip of Kyushu**, probably to get as far away as possible from this home. They talk in a thick accent there, and well...l wouldn't call it bullying, but I was made fun of, and I didn't have any friends.

Assuming that the tip she's referring to is the southernmost part of [Kyushu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyushu), 'all the way out on the tip of Kyushu' may refer to a place somewhere on the [Okinawa prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawa_Prefecture#Major_islands) (possibly within the [Yaeyama islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaeyama_Islands)). So, it could refer to an accent unique to people who speak the Okinawan language or dialect.